# How to redirect old magento urls after adding store code urls

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting

We added store codes to our urls (Add Store Code to Urls in admin) and now all our old urls are broken.

How do we rewrite all old urls to the new ones with the store codes?

Example: `category/test/` (old url, broken) to `en/category/test` (new url with store code, working).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way out of the box.

And you have the problem, that the old url is ambiguous over the store views.

I would try to add a line to the `.htaccess`  like:

```
RewriteRule !^en/ en%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```

I'm not well in `mod_rewrite`, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Yes we do have the problem that our urls have no parameters indicating the store view.

Comment: Your solution works if one had one store view, the problem is we've got three (three languages).

Comment: There must be a Magento core file in where we redirect any url that has no store code prefix...

Comment: I think we found a solution. It's weird and simple but it works.

Comment: After enabling store code urls in admin, we removed suffixes (we used a slash /), and now all old slash-suffixed urls (the ones that are indexed) redirect to the new store code prefixed urls without the slash suffix. Good enough for us!

Comment: Hi @vik could you please explain how you did this a bit more? I am having same issue. Where did you remove the suffix?